# Calculate total price for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to calculate the price for multiple rows. I have it working for one row however, the onchange function doesn't seem to work when i put it into my for loop. Does anyone know why that is?

**JavaScritpt:**

```
function cal()
{
    var price = document.getElementById('priceper_0').value;
    var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_0').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_0'.value;


    document.getElementById('subtotal_0').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity).toFixed(2);


}
```

**php/HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Paper</td>
<td align="center">Price</td>
<td align="center">Per Pack</td>
<td align="center">Quantity</td>
<td align="center">Sub Total</td>
</tr>

<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_0" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="cal();"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_0" class="txt" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
</tr>

<?php
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) 
{
 echo '<tr class="multipp">';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="cal();" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is id problem,you should use unique id for elements

Try with this

Pass your `$i` to the `calc()` function then do the function like below

```
onChange=cal($i)
```

Function

```
function cal($i)
{
    var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+$i+'').value;
    var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+$i+'').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+$i+'').value;


    document.getElementById('subtotal_'+$i+'').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity).toFixed(2);


}
```

Comment: do i need to change the id's in the <td><input/></td> to match the id's in the function?

Comment: yes @user3009232 pass i to the function then try above method

Comment: i have passed the $i to my cal function and have renamed the id's to match the ones in my cal function. What happens now is that my text is displayed in the second row as opposed to the first row and it has stopped calculating and the sub total field is blank :S

Answer (score 0):

I think with multiple rows, you should be giving the number of the row to your cal function so it can work with the correct row in there not always the number 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can try onblur as well, this means on leaving textbox focus. what are the arrays you are using in you form value is your form generating fine.

if form is generated fine, you can do it like this as well, Pass your $i to the cal() like, cal($i) for each row in your html.

```
function cal(ind)
{
    var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+ind+').value;
    var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+ind+').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+ind+'.value;


     document.getElementById('subtotal_'+ind').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity).toFixed(2);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to an input field the php row count and then from javascript take this number and with a for loop calc all rows proces. 
Have a look in below code.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Paper</td>
    <td align="center">Price</td>
    <td align="center">Per Pack</td>
    <td align="center">Quantity</td>
    <td align="center">Sub Total</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="multipp">
    <td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_0" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="cal();"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_0" class="txt" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<10; $i++) 
    {
     echo '<tr class="multipp">';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="calSubTotal(<?=$i?>);" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
<br />
Total: <input type="text" name="Total" id="Total" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rowcounter" id="rowcounter" value="<?=$i?>: />
    <?php /*In this example the row counter is alwase 10 */ ?>
```

Then in javascript code use a loop

```
function calAllRows()
{
    var rowsCounter = document.getElementById('rowcounter').value;
    vat totalValue = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<rowsCounter ;i++)
    {
      var price = document.getElementById('priceper_' + i + '').value;
      var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_' + i + '').value;
      var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + i + ''.value;
      totalValue += (price/per_pack)*quantity;
    }


    document.getElementById('Total').value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
}

function calSubTotal(var i)
{
     var subTotalValue = 0;

      var price = document.getElementById('priceper_' + i + '').value;
      var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_' + i + '').value;
      var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + i + ''.value;
      subTotalValue += (price/per_pack)*quantity;


    document.getElementById('Total').value = subTotalValue.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTotal($i)
{
var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+$i+'').value;
var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+$i+'').value;
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+$i+'').value;

document.getElementById('subtotal_'+$i+'').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Paper</td>
<td align="center">Price</td>
<td align="center">Per Pack</td>
<td align="center">Quantity</td>
<td align="center">Sub Total</td>
</tr>
<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal(<?php echo $i;?>);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr class="multipp">';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal('.$i.');" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" />`</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```